# Causality as a product of creation

Tags: causality

Got a short quest if creation gives rise to time and the world.
Our perception allows observation of that world and we interpret events within it as a result of which we describe as causality.
Action and reaction cause and effect.
This observation leads to a contradiction since any creation requires action which creation is the effect of that action.
Without time you cannot have causality because causality is a sequence of cause and effect and requires time to afford sequence.
So the world could not be a result of creation since creation is the reaction or effect of a cause that requires the presence of time. 
So do we conclude time is eternal to allow the causal nature any creation requires and confirm the correctness in our perception of causality from observation.

Comment: This is quite unreadable. Try to separate this into some different sentences so we are helped to try to follow your reasoning.

Comment: Causation does not require presence of time on many theological views, see the [Cosmological Argument](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/cosmological-argument), and one can not infer causality from observations, as Hume pointed out.

Comment: how can causation give rise to time? What do you mean by creation? Something out of nothing? What was there before time? Your own thoughts are bound by time, space, and causation. Time, space, and causality have had no beginning and will have no end.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda scientific argument proposes that the big bang was the point of creation, dimension matter energy information and time was a result of the big bang and the argument suggest you cannot say before the big bang because time was created from it. I was trying to put forward an argument that the big bang was creation, and any creation needs a sequence of action and reaction and you cannot have sequence without time. I propose that time is eternal from my argument and the big bang created spacial dimension and its contents which we observe in a causal manner and not time.

Comment: @Conifold are you saying language is formed from the presence of causality, without using language to form a reasoned argument to give rise to the concept, the concept simply gives rise to its own conclusion from its immutable presence then language forms to enable communication of this concept.

Comment: The argument that causality is not a product of observation results in either a negation of this argument as a function of time or time does not give rise to its argument and time does not afford the nature of causality and its only speculation of observation. I can grasp that but things happpen as a consequence of action from my observation if causality is not a product of time then everything is zero point, cause effect cause of that effect yada yada happened without time and results in unobservation if everything is simultaneous then how can we have sequence every event occurs simultaneous.